Storing ETH on token address
I like to create a token contract which can be created via ether transfer and also redeemed back to ether. Is it a good idea to store this ether on the contact address, or are there more secure patterns to do it?

Please explain your exact question/requirement.

The simpler the better, so it's a good idea to keep the ETH in the contract.
You can always take a look at the most used WETH contract, the ETH is stored at the same address.
